# How to store GDAL objects in a geodjango Geometry object?

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango

I have a GeoDjango GeometryField in my database:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = CharField()
    geometry = models.GeometryField()
```

I'm trying to load certain parts of shapefiles into my database.

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
datasource = DataSource("file.shp")
layer = datasource[0]

for each in layer:
    name = each.get("NAME") # To obtain the name
    ... (some more logic to add properties and validate which objects should be imported)
    Place.objects.create(
        name = name,
        geometry = each.geom
    )
```

However, this returns this error:

> Cannot set Place SpatialProxy (GEOMETRY) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries.MultiPolygon'>

I'm not sure exactly how I have to transform this `gdal.geometries.MultiPolygon` object so that it can be stored in the database. I've tried using:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import OGRGeometry
geometry = OGRGeometry(each.geom)
```

But this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at the source of the [GeoDjango LayerMapping utility](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/gis/utils/layermapping.py), and it seems to convert GDAL geometries to WKT.

You should be able to set the value with something like this:

```py
Place.objects.create(
    name = name,
    geometry = each.geom.wkt  # note the .wkt at the end
)
```